# hide or show user fields registragion based on selected role when admin is adding a user

Tags: drupal-7, field, user-roles

is there any module to allow me like administrator to add user of differents roles and show or hide dynamically fields corresponding to those roles when I am adding them?

For example, I have two roles (father and son) and I have tho user custom fields in user registration form (work and school), if I am adding a user with the father role, the school field should be hidden immediately and marked not required. and if I am adding user with the son role, the work field should be hidden and marked like not required, and the school field should be shown and marked like required. and if I mark both roles, both fields should be displayed and be required.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields ? I used this on custom content type before but never tried to use it on user roles.